# Scroll to class in angular 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, scroll

Very simple question, how can I scroll to a class in angular, searched for hours to make this work, so frustating
I have a calendar component, and when I click a day, the events for that day open underneath

Works with pure javascript for an id, but not class

```
 const elmnt = document.getElementById('scrollto');
 elmnt.scrollIntoView(true);
```

I also have jQuery available but this is not scrolling at all

```
 if ($('.call-open').length > 0) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.call-open').offset().top
      }, 2000);
    }
```

this .call-open class get's added after I click the day, maybe that's why

I tried [this](https://github.com/nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to) plugin but it doesn't do anything, even with a simple example button

I can't be the only one with this problem, yet I can't find any working solution, sometines angular is a pain in the ass for simple things like this

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue if the elements are added or classes are set after the click event. Introduce a small delay using `setTimeout()` before calling your code as a test.

Comment: this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/49875416/4399281

Comment: @FatehMohamed this is for routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works, but damn it's ugly

```
 window.setTimeout(() => {
  if ($('.cal-open').length > 0) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.cal-open').offset().top - 80
    }, 100);
  }
}, (250));
```

Comment: and I need jQuery, I need it for something else in that page too but still a solutions without jQuery would be nice

Answer (score 4):

try this with timeout

```
scroll(){
 setTimeout(() => {
    const classElement = document.getElementsByClassName('scrollTo');
    if(classElement.length > 0){
      classElement[0].scrollIntoView();
    }
 }
 }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem using the following code:

```
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  scrollToFirstInvalidControl() {
    const firstInvalidControl: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(
      "class-name"
    );
    if (!firstInvalidControl) return false
    window.scroll({
      top: this.getTopOffset(firstInvalidControl),
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }

  getTopOffset(controlEl: HTMLElement): number {
    const labelOffset = 50;
    return controlEl.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - labelOffset;
  }
```